# PHP regex for .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, rest

Say I have a page testpage.php and I want to access it through localhost/testpage . I can't figure out the regex to get it to work.

When I use the following, I get a server error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* "^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+*.php"/$0
```

However, when I specify the exact file it works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* testpage.php/$0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

the third line checks if the file actually exists before doing the rewrite to avoid errors

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

It will rewrite the filename with .php extention

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a regular expression in the replacement pattern. That's why it fails.
In this line

```
RewriteRule .* "^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+*.php"/$0
```

You are telling Apache to rewrite anything ( `.*` ) to the literal `"^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+*.php"/`, plus the zeroth matched string (which is an error anyway, because matches start from $1, then there is $2 etc.).

If you want to capture a match you must surround it with parentheses, like

```
(.*)
```

and then it will be available in the replacement string as `$1`.